# remove index.php from url: google cloud

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using google cloud compute engine for hosting my site.

I want to remove the index.php from the url and also google cloud dont support .htaccess.

```
http://domain_name.com/index.php/home
```

to

```
http://domain_name.com/home
```

Comment: Could [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/url-map) be what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you share your `app.yaml` ? Didn't check the cloud tag

Comment: @Script47 can you please guide, how [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/url-map)  will have help me to remove `index.php` from overall site.

Comment: I've never used GCE but I thought I'd try Google it for you and that's what came up. Unsure how helpful it is but I thought, seeing as you know GCE it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Compute Engines are Linux (or other OS) machines that you can configure however you want. If you want to use `.htaccess`, configure Apache accordingly and it works just fine on Compute Engine.

Are you maybe using [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/)?